# game of stacks in which number is removed from top until it amounts to greater that given max sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, data-structures, stack

I'm trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/game-of-two-stacks/problem?isFullScreen=true) hacker rank problem, which gives us two integer stacks and a `maxSum` variable assigned to a particular value and asks us to find total number of elements removed from top from both the stacks until sum of all number removed from stacks does not become greater than the given `maxSum`.

example;

```
stack 1 is; 4 2 4 6 1
stack 2 is; 2 1 8 5
maxSum=10
output=4 as we can remove 4,2,2, 1 & 4+2+2+1=9 which is less than 10.
```

I used below approach to implement my function to solve it and according to me everything in my code looks fine, but still i'm unable to pass many of the testcases. Kindly looking for help.

ps: i'm beginner in DSA.

```
int twoStacks(int maxSum, vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
    int count=0;
    int sum=0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while(sum<=maxSum){
        if(i<a.size() && j<b.size() && sum+min(a[i],b[j])<=maxSum){
            sum+=min(a[i],b[j]);
            count++;
            if(min(a[i],b[j])==a[i]){
                i++;
            }
            else{
                j++;
            }
        }
        else if(i>=a.size() && j<b.size() && sum+b[j]<=maxSum){
            sum+=b[j];
            count++;
            j++;
        }
        else if(i<a.size() && j>=b.size() && sum+a[i]<=maxSum){
            sum+=a[i];
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Looking briefly at the problem constraints and off the top of my head, I would say your approach definitely won't work because the stacks are not sorted. One valid approach is to compute the partial sum of both "stacks". You then find the index where the partial sum of `a` exceeds `maxSum`. Now, start walking through the partial sum of `b` and add to whatever you reached in `a`. Whenever you exceed `maxSum`, decrement the index of `a`. Continue until you reach the end of `b`. Track the maximum total of both indices of `a` and `b` for any valid sum. This value will be the answer, in O(N) time.

Comment: Your algorithm is to always remove the smallest item from the top of the two stacks.  Since a larger item could be covering smaller ones below, that may not yield the best answer.  Consider that stacks [1, 3, 3, 3, 3] and [4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] with the maxSum = 10.  In this case, you'd want to start with the 4 so that you can get to the 1's below.

Comment: You have not phrased the code challenge correctly. It does not just ask *"...to find total number of elements removed"*, but the **maximum** possible number of elements removed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code assumes that there is a "greedy" approach to ensure you find the **maximum** possible number of removals. But this is not true. It is not always best to take the minimum value among the two stack tops. For example, stack B could start with a rather great value, but have many small values after it, which would make it interesting to still take that first great value and then profit from the many subsequent values you can take from it:

```
maxSum: 10
A: {5, 5, 5, 5}
B: {6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

Your algorithm would take twice from A, while it is better to take 5 times from B.

So first take as many as possible from A, and if you can take them all, also continue taking as many from B. This represents one possible solution.

Then continue to take one less value from A and see if you then can take more from B. This again represents a potential solution. Continue this process until either no elements from A can be returned to it, or all values of B have been taken.

Among all potential solutions keep track of the most removals that could be done.

Code:

```
int twoStacks(int maxSum, vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int maxTakes = 0;
    // Take as many as possible from A
    while (i < a.size() && maxSum >= a[i]) {
        maxSum -= a[i++];
    }
    while (true) {
        // Take as many as possible from B
        while (j < b.size() && maxSum >= b[j]) {
            maxSum -= b[j++];
        }
        maxTakes = max(maxTakes, i + j);
        if (i == 0 || j >= b.size()) return maxTakes;
        // Return one value back to A so to make room for more from B
        maxSum += a[--i];
    }
    return maxTakes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking elements from A until you reach or exceed the target.

Then, repeatedly remove elements from A until you fall short of the target, and add elements from B until you once again meet or exceed it.

Keep track of the largest excess.

Example Ruby code that passes all tests:

```
def twoStacks(max_sum, a, b)
    # curSum is the sum of the elements of `a` 
    # and `b` up to their indexes
    a_index = -1
    b_index = -1
    cur_sum = 0
    max_score = 0
    
    # Start with the initial, greedy score
    # found by taking successive elements of `a`
    # then `b` until we get to the max_sum
    while cur_sum <= max_sum 
        if a_index <= a.size - 2
            a_index += 1
            cur_sum += a[a_index]
        elsif b_index <= b.size - 2
            b_index += 1 
            cur_sum += b[b_index]
        else
            return a_index + b_index + 2 if cur_sum <= max_sum
        end
        max_score = a_index + b_index + 2 if cur_sum <= max_sum 
    end
        
    # Now we keep reducing `a_index` or increasing
    # `b_index` as needed to find the max score
    while true
        if cur_sum > max_sum
            return max_score if a_index < 0
            cur_sum -= a[a_index]
            a_index -= 1
        else
            b_index += 1
            return max_score if b_index >= b.size
            cur_sum += b[b_index]
        end
        max_score = [max_score, a_index + b_index + 2].max if cur_sum <= max_sum
    end
end
```